# Is there DPI-C compatible types for <stdint.h> types?

Tags: c, system-verilog, system-verilog-dpi

I was attempting to write a struct compatible with DPI-C for Verilog.

The struct is as follows:

```
/* Microcontroller FW config */
struct ucode_image_config {
    uintptr_t src_addr;
    uint32_t size;
};
```

In DPI-C the code is as follows:

```
/* Microcontroller FW configuration */
typedef struct {
  int unsigned src_addr;
  int unsigned size;
} ucode_image_config_t;
```

I assume this is not a 1-1 equivalence because of the variable size of `uintptr_t`, so I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

SystemVerilog does not have pointers, so there is no compatible pointer data type between C and SystemVerilog. It does a an opaque pointer called a `chandle` which allows you to pass a C pointer from one DPI-C routine to another. But there is no way to reference anything using the chandle from the SystemVerilog side without importing another DPI-C access routine.

The DPI has the concept of Open arrays (Section 35.5.6.1 in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595). You should take a look at that and probably ask another question giving details on the intent of what you are trying to accomplish.